# Count number of results from Expressions With Ones and Twos

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, number-theory

Given at most X number of 1s and at most Y number of 2s. How many different evaluation results are possible when they are formed in an expression containing only addition + sign and multiplication * sign are allowed?

Note that, multiplication takes precedence over addition.

For example, if X=2 and Y=2, then we have the following expressions:

```
1, 1*1 = 1
2, 1*2, 1*1*2, 1+1 = 2
1+2, 1+1*2 = 3
2+2, 2*2, 1+1+2, 1*2*2, 1*1*2*2, 1*2+1*2, 1*1*2+2, 1*2+2 = 4
1+2+2, 1+1*2+2 = 5
1+1+2+2 = 6
```

So there are 6 unique results that can be formed if X = 2 and Y = 2.
So here answer would be 6.

---

#### Source

This question is from  [March 2014 Hacker Rank contest](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/mar14/challenges/ones-and-twos) which has ended by now.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have already tried looking for this problem's solution and also tried answering it myself. I have already wasted a lot of time so maybe, I thought it's better to ask for a solution and study what mistakes I've made.

Comment: There is an editorial on the Hackerrank page. I think all you need to unlock it is to sign in, which one can do from a Google account.